# A little CSS logic based on image size

Tags: css, html, png

This is kind of a peculiar problem. I am working on a header for a custom form where a logo is on the right side of the header and header text is centered within the logo banner.[image: header1]

In general, logos are narrow, so I want to center the text in the main container div like this:

In a few cases, if the logo is very long, I want to center the text on the left side. This is easy enough to do by creating a div that floats left and centering the text within:
[image: header2]

The tricky part here (and I'm not sure it is even possible) is making the header text centered on the left side if and only if the image size is beyond a certain length. Oh--and I can't use Javascript.

Wondering if there are any CSS tricks that can get me there...

Comment: What you are asking for cannot be done using CSS because CSS is not aware of how wide the logo is and cannot set a text alignment value based on an image width.  You need JavaScript for these types of problems.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking--but I was wondering if I might be able to do some sort of trick with min-width/max-width on a hidden div. There again, it would require Javascript to display it beyond a certain length...

Comment: From a design point of view, what you are trying to do makes sense if you have a small enough screen, which suggest that you might be able to use a media query and alter the style based on the screen width.  From a visual layout point of view, the width of the logo is only relevant with how it compares to the screen size.  A 2 inch logo on a 24 inch monitor is still pretty small, but on a 4 inch screen, rather enormous.

Comment: I didn't make the requirement... :-)  Wondering if perhaps I put the header text on an internal div and do not allow it to overflow.